# Estimating the proportion of a multivariate normal distribution that's not fully contained within variable-specific intervals using a sample

Tags: standard-deviation, estimators, prediction-interval, multivariate-normal-distribution

**Scenario:** You sample a number of observations (say, 20) from a multivariate normal distribution of, say, 3 variables. The variables will typically be positively intercorrelated, but little else is known about them. You compute the sample means and standard deviations of each variable. Using these, you construct an interval for each variable that span [mean - 2 SDs; mean + 2 SDs], so you have three intervals.

**Question:** Can you, using only the information contained in the sample and the assumption that the sample was drawn from a multivariate normal distribution, estimate the proportion of observations that will fall outside at least one of the respective three intervals if you take a large new sample from the same multivariate distribution?

**Example:** (using R):

You observe the following sample:

```
my_sample <- structure(c(0.435549035598253, -0.733233794669011,
1.11031819215666, -1.42156636159226, -0.470466348416922, 
-0.344544376519479, -3.16140380323258, 1.25911320034122, 
-0.505015560013396, -0.27245327626564, 0.69950457554912, 
-0.549955837569371, 0.804997707814359, -0.308465377431691, 
-0.0686566378218331, 0.55621330641487, -2.15129256390727, 1.51382617869646, 
-0.800769937952146, 0.0695413334342196, 0.906269766423279, 
0.468478559989297, 1.4336687374579, -1.55045691958889, -0.962196997062294, 
-0.491428475600102, -1.05473041129592, 1.96984949987731,
-0.364288431419078, -0.501212009426657), .Dim = c(10L, 3L), 
.Dimnames = list(NULL, NULL))
```

The SD-based intervals for the three variables are:

```
[, 1]: [-2.95; 2.13]
[, 2]: [-2.07; 2.02]
[, 3]: [-2.33; 2.30]
```

If you sample a larger number of new observations from the original multivariate distribution, which proportion of them will fall outside at least one of the respective SD-based intervals? (i.e., smaller than -2.95 or larger than 2.13 for the first variable; smaller than -2.07 or larger than 2.02 for the second; smaller than -2.33 or larger than 2.30 for the third)

Comment: You are asking at least four questions: the first question interprets your intervals as a multivariate *tolerance interval* while (A) interpret them as *prediction intervals.*  The possibility (B) multiplies those by two, giving four questions.  One wonders whether you have a statistical problem that might be solved better by means of a good tolerance or prediction interval procedure, and if so what that question might be.

Comment: I've reformulated the question. I agree that the procedure outlined in my question is a poor solution to the problem it tries to address - this is precisely the point I want to make. To illustrate this, an answer to my question would be useful (if one exists).